# How to shutdown remote Win2k8 machine using WMIC?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-access, wmi

What is the exact syntax to shutdown remote Win2k8 server using WMIC?

(The reason WMIC must be used is because the remote machine in a different NT Domain and the local machine does not have access to that domain. WMIC takes /user: and /password: parameters and auths against remote machine itself.)

These don't work:

> wmic /node:10.162.x.x /user:tech1\xxxx /password:xxxx os call Shutdown
>
> Executing (Win32_OperatingSystem)->Shutdown()
>
> ERROR: Code = 0x8004102f Description = Invalid method Parameter(s)
>
> Facility = WMI

---

> wmic /node:10.162.x.x /user:tech1\xxxx /password:xxxx os call Shutdown(1)
>
> Verb Or Method has no input parameters.

---

> wmic /node:10.162.x.x /user:tech1\xxxx /password:xxxx os call Win32Shutdown(1)
>
> Executing (Win32_OperatingSystem)->Win32Shutdown()
>
> ERROR:
>
> Code = 0x8004102f
>
> Description = Invalid method Parameter(s)
>
> Facility = WMI

---

> wmic /node:10.162.x.x /user:tech1\xxxx /password:xxxx path Win32_OperatingSystem call Shutdown(1)
>
> Verb Or Method has no input parameters.

---

> wmic /node:10.162.x.x /user:tech1\xxxx /password:xxxx path Win32_OperatingSystem call Shutdown
>
> Executing (Win32_OperatingSystem)->Shutdown()
>
> ERROR:
> Code = 0x8004102f
> Description = Invalid method Parameter(s)
> Facility = WMI

Comment: any reason to not just use shutdown /m

Comment: @tony: "The reason WMIC must be used is because the remote machine in a different NT Domain and the local machine does not have access to that domain. WMIC takes /user: and /password: parameters and auths against remote machine itself."

Comment: gut feeling is that you'll need a where clause to qualify what your rebooting.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why WMIC wont work, but the powershell version does work:

```
$cred = get-credential tech1\xxxxx
(gwmi -comp 10.162.x.x -cred $cred Win32_OperatingSystem).Shutdown()
```

You'll be prompted for the password, there's no way around it prompting you for the password.

Comment: this really is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

the 1st one but you need a space between the ipaddress and the /user:

**add a where clause**

something like

wmic os where "version like '%'" call win32shutdown 2

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic /node: "machinename" os where primary="true" call shutdown
```

Must have space after :  Must have quotes around machinename and true

use `/user:username` between machinename and os if you need to authenticate

Comment: Hello and welcome to serverfault. Please take the time to format and comment sample code when posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WMIC /node:COMPUTER process call create “cmd.exe /c shutdown”
```